# Motion sensor fogger

Tags: amperage

I am just wondering if there a way to attach a motion sensor rated for 2.5 amps to a fog machine that requires 4 amps?

I’d like to replace the manual switch on the fogger with the motion sensor. At this point if I just hook it up as is the sensor will trigger the fogger but then gets stuck in the on position and will not shut off.

I assume it’s because the fogger is drawing too much and won’t allow closure for whatever reason.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I am just wondering if there a way to attach a motion sensor rated for 2.5 amps to a fog machine that requires 4 amps?

Yes. Use the normally-open (NO) contact of a suitably rated relay (paying attention to whether the fogger is AC or DC rated). The contacts must be rated for the voltage and current being switched. The coil should be rated for the voltage output by the motion sensor.

> I’d like to replace the manual switch on the fogger with the motion sensor.

That should be fine.

> At this point if I just hook it up as is the sensor will trigger the fogger but then gets stuck in the on position and will not shut off.

Without details of the internals of your motion sensor and fogger any answer will be a guess.

> I assume it’s because the fogger is drawing too much and won’t allow closure for whatever reason.

In electrical circuits "closure" means conducting. Your problem is that the switch won't open. Again, no details.

Comment: The motor inside unit just says 120v 60hz...

Comment: I have added some photos which I hope helps... and yes the circuit stays closed and will not open like it should. I’m using the test setting on the sensor hoping I can use it for 5 second bursts of fog.

Answer (score 1):

The fog machine is rated at **400W** and the motion sensor is only rated for a **300W** resistive load.
You need to have the motion sensor control a relay that is capable of handling the 400W load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIgJkn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>